# Processing - Changing direction with collision

Tags: boolean, processing, collision, detection

I'm struggling to use the rectangle collision tool. I'm trying to make a program where the image changes direction when two images collide.

I want to use this code but I'm uncertain where I put it? Also what do I substitute for ob1 (object1) and x1 and where do I put the width and height variables?  Thanks

```
 boolean Collision()

  ( ob1 - x1, ob1 -y1, ob1 - w, ob1 - h,
    ob2 - x1, ob2 -y1, ob2 -w, ob2-h)

  return 
  (ob1 - x1 < ob2 - x2 && ob1 - x2 > ob2 = x1 &&  //insert y variables








//start of code


    class Bouncy 
    {

      int x;
      int y;
      int dx; 
      int dy;

      PImage nw, ne, sw, se;

      Bouncy(int x, int y, int dx, int dy) 
      {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    nw = loadImage("NorthW.png");
    ne = loadImage("NorthE.png");
    sw = loadImage("SouthW.png");
    se = loadImage("SouthE.png");
      }


      void update() 
      {
        render();
        move();
      }

      void render() 
      {
    if (dx == -1 && dy == -1)
      image(nw,x,y);

    else if (dx == 1 && dy == -1)
    image(ne,x,y);

    else if (dx == -1 && dy == 1)
    image(sw,x,y);

    else if (dx == 1 && dy == 1)
    image(se,x,y);
          }

      void checkCollisions() 
      {
        int edge = 65; // half width of one of the PNG files

        if (y<=(edge-edge)) // hit top border
     dy=1; // switch to moving downwards

    if (y>=500-(edge*2)) // hit bottom border
     dy=-1; // switch to moving upwards

        if (x<=edge-edge) // hit left border
    dx=1; // switch to moving right

    if (x>=500-(edge*2)) // hit right border
    dx=-1;
      }



      void move() 
      {
    checkCollisions();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

      }
    }

    Bouncy janet,jeff,jerry;

    void setup() 
    {
      size(500,500);
      janet = new Bouncy(10,100,1,-1);
      jeff = new Bouncy(10,150,-1,1);
      jerry = new Bouncy(10,350,1,1);

    }

    void draw() 
    {
      background(255);
      janet.update();
      jeff.update();
      jerry.update();

    }
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. Right now it's very hard to read.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Not really. Your indentation is still way off, which makes it very hard to read. Note that the Processing editor (and most other IDEs) will automatically format your code for you.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a step back and [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those pieces on one at a time. For example: instead of trying to work on your full program, why don't you start simpler with two hard-coded rectangles that change color when they're intersecting?

That will allow you to get your basic collision detection working without worrying about all the extra stuff. Because right now your collision detection code doesn't make a ton of sense. You need to compare two rectangles, not just one. Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on collision detection available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection). You're looking for rectangle-rectangle collision detection:

```
if(rectOneRight > rectTwoLeft && rectOneLeft < rectTwoRight && rectOneBottom > rectTwoTop && rectOneTop < rectTwoBottom){
   // colliding!
}
```

Get that working with two hard-coded rectangles. Then get it working with a third. If you get stuck on a specific step, then you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific question. Good luck.

Comment: I'm really struggling with substituting images with the rectangle method while making them change direction. Is it possible to use the code I've added above? Thanks

Comment: @JHaskins Images **are** rectangles. Get it working with basic rectangles first, then try adding images.

Comment: Is the boolean method also doable?

Comment: @JHaskins What exactly do you mean by the boolean method? I've given you the approach you need to take. Have you tried starting with a simpler program that just contains two hard-coded rectangles?

Comment: Yes, I have two rectangles bouncing from the sides and from each other using the codes from your website but don't know how to substitute for images.

Comment: @JHaskins Images are rectangles. What about that is confusing you? An image has an X, Y, width, and height, just like a rectangle. Again, start with a simpler program: can you create a small program that just shows a single rectangle? Then can you modify that program to show an image there instead?